# How to return different type based upon template parameter

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, templates, visual-c++, template-meta-programming

I would like to create a template function that returns either `int` or `std::vector<int>` depending on a template parameter. For example:

```
struct ReturnInt {};
struct ReturnVec {};

[...]

int num = func<ReturnInt>();
std::vector<int> nums = func<ReturnVec>();
```

I've been attempting naively to implement this based on my very limited experience with TMP. I feel like it should involve something along the lines of explicit template specializations, `std::enable_if`, `std::conditional`, and/or SFINAE. But none of my attempts to code this will compile, let alone run in a simple test.

How would this return-type switching be implemented?

**Edit:** As noted in the comments, this is a simplification of my actual problem. If it helps, I have a class that accepts a template parameter. Depending on the parameter, I would like its `get()` method to return either a single object/value, or a standard container of objects/values.

Comment: Why do the functions need to be named the same, if they're not disambiguating based on parameter or anything like that? Treating the template specialization as part of the name just seems unnecessary.

Comment: This is a simplification of my actual problem. If it helps, I have a class that accepts a template parameter. Depending on the parameter, I would like its `get()` method to return either a single object/value, or a standard container of objects/values.

Comment: Have you looked at template specialization?

Comment: @BretKuhns: That's actually pretty easy, since you're asking about a class. You can define the class to have different `get()` methods in different specializations.

Comment: @AdrianCornish I have, but when I tried it, MSVC was giving me an error that my specializations had different return types.

Comment: @BretKuhns: You can't specialize individual functions like that. But you can specialize the class as a whole.

Comment: @BretKuhns Can you add a tag for your compiler then - these things work differently

Comment: @BretKuhns Why not this works fine `#include <vector>

template<class T>
T foo(T a)
{
}

template<>
int foo(int a)
{
}

template<>
std::vector<int> foo(std::vector<int> a)
{
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

  return 0;
}
`

Comment: @KevinBallard So this is a solution that works? What is your issue?

Comment: @AdrianCornish: That works only because the template parameter itself is used as the return type. If you can't do that, then it won't work.

Comment: @KevinBallard It answers the OP's question of `How to return different type based upon template parameter` :-)

Comment: @AdrianCornish: Sure, if you ignore his real problem and just blindly answer based on the title of the problem. Presumably if Bret could have used `int` and `std::vector<int>` as his template parameters he would have already done that.

Comment: BTW, if you do need to specialize a non-member function's return type without actually matching your template parameter, you can use a helper class to define the type. https://gist.github.com/3735385

Comment: @KevinBallard Without checking standard compliance g++ happily compiles `#include <vector>

template<class T>
T foo()
{
}

template<>
int foo()
{
}

template<>
std::vector<int> foo()
{
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   char c=foo<char>();
   int i=foo<int>();
   std::vector<int> v=foo<std::vector<int> >();

  return 0;
}
` for me

Comment: @AdrianCornish: Yes, because that's valid. You're missing the point. You can specialize `foo<int>` to have a return type of `int`. But you can't specialize `foo<SomeArbitraryType>` to have a return type of `int`, unless `int` is somehow statically derivable from `SomeArbitraryType` (which is what I used the `spec_info` helper class for in my gist).

Comment: @AdrianCornish: Basically, the template specialization and the generic version must both have identical type signatures.

Comment: @KevinBallard Lightbulb just turned on :-) gotchya

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your edit, you just want a bog-standard template specialization

```
struct ReturnsInt{};
struct ReturnsVec{};

template<typename T>
class Foo {};

template<>
class Foo<ReturnsInt> {
public:
    int get() { return 3; }
};

template<>
class Foo<ReturnsVec> {
public:
    std::vector<int> get() {
        return {3};
    }
};
```

---

If you only want to modify one member function based on the template, but reuse the rest of the class definition, you can use a helper class

```
struct ReturnsInt{};
struct ReturnsVec{};

class helper_Foo {
public:
    string bar() {
        return "this is a shared method";
    }
};

template<typename T>
class Foo : public helper_Foo {};

template<>
class Foo<ReturnsInt> : public helper_Foo {
public:
    int get() { return 3; }
};

template<>
class Foo<ReturnsVec> : public helper_Foo {
public:
    std::vector<int> get() {
        return {3};
    }
};
```

Comment: This works beautifully, but this technique seems troublesome when I have more than the single `get` method in `Foo`. I can't share the methods across specializations of the class.

Comment: @BretKuhns: Put your actual class implementation in a helper class, and derive your templated class from that helper class. Then you can just define the `get()` member function in the templated class and let everything else come from the parent helper class.